# RE.Match any two values in a cell with another cell

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-re

I am currently trying to match two cells in two different spreadsheets which I am able to do so far but now I am having a issue where there is multiple values in one cell and I would like to match two occurances in the cell against a cell that has loads of information.

For example:

(title) - Data A Cell:
Car Model Variation 90-92

(year) - Data B Cell:
1990|1991|1992|1993|1994|1995|1996|1997|1998|1999

```
import re

if re.match(year, title):
   print("Success")
```

But i want to try and match any two values of data B in the title but not sure best way to approach the problem.

Comment: Something like [this](https://ideone.com/lDa0rU)? The regex will look like `\b(?:90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99)\b` and will match [like this](https://regex101.com/r/v5DSzL/1).

Comment: This works really well thank you. is there anyway to make it require two years to be found to return a true value?

Comment: Do you mean you want to only return true when there are two 2-digit years separated with a hyphen? Like in [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v5DSzL/2)?

Comment: very close but keep the 1998 (4 digit sequence) but only return true if there is two matches such as in the demo above if 1990 is found and if 1992 is found then return true but only return true if two occurances are found not one.

Comment: Ok, https://ideone.com/fBdZrl?

Comment: Amazing thank you. i used it in a re.search but used similar method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build your pattern dynamically like

```
p = "|".join([x[2:] for x in year.split("|")])
rx = re.compile(rf'(?s)\b(?:{p})\b.*?\b(?:{p})\b')
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7lGsKh/1), it will match only when it finds two occurrences of a two-digit year in a string. Pattern details:

- `(?s)` - `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` inline modifier flag that lets `.` match line break chars
- `\b(?:90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99)\b` - `90`, `91`..`99` as a whole word
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\b(?:90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99)\b` - `90`, `91`..`99` as a whole word

See [full Python demo](https://ideone.com/fBdZrl):

```
import re
titles = [r'Car Model Variation 90-92',r'Car Model Variation 90']
year = r'1990|1991|1992|1993|1994|1995|1996|1997|1998|1999'
p = "|".join([x[2:] for x in year.split("|")])
rx = re.compile(rf'(?s)\b(?:{p})\b.*?\b(?:{p})\b')

for title in titles:
  print ( f"'{title}' =>", bool(rx.search(title)) )
```

Output:

```
'Car Model Variation 90-92' => True
'Car Model Variation 90' => False
```